# NoSuchMethodError on one machine but not the other

Tags: java, netbeans, nosuchmethoderror

I have this application which you can run in batch mode with java macros. I have a `mymacro.java` that uses `myjar.jar`. For simplicity's sake I put them all in the same directory from which I am running the application, so the classpath is `"./myjar.jar"`.

The command to run the application is:

```
theapplication -classpath "./myjar.jar" -batch mymacro.java
```

where the `-classpath` tag does what it advertises, i.e. override the classpath. Now this runs fine on my Windows XP PC. However, I get a `NoSuchMethodError` when running the exact same thing on a Linux cluster.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.foo.bar.baz.theMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

I can't figure this one out. Same .java, same .jar, same `theMethod`. The classpath can't get any simpler. Other methods in `myjar.jar` are being called without any errors. What could be going wrong?

FYI, I set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable to `"."` on both machines to rule out any conflicts.

**EDIT**

Output of `java -version` on my Windows XP PC:

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

On Linux cluster:

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: what OS are you running?

Comment: Mhm.. strange could you possibly post the output of the command `java -version` on both machines? Maybe this could be a point of difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh. The application contained a NetBeans module that basically contained the same code as an earlier version of my JAR file. So my java macro was preferentially accessing the methods in the older NBM, not those in my newer JAR file.

The error went away when I uninstalled the NBM.

Nice way to waste a full day of work!

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue once due to the file names of the JAR files used. In my case, I had multiple JAR files like `a.jar`, `b.jar`, `m.jar` and `N.jar`. A single class was duplicated in both `m.jar` and `N.jar`.

On Windows, everything used to work as `N.jar` was always getting loaded after `m.jar`. But after burning much midnight oil, I discovered that the issue on *nix was due to the fact that `N.jar` gets loaded first followed by `a.jar`, `b.jar`, `m.jar` as file names are case sensitive on *nix unlike on Windows.

Just make sure you don't have any similar issue.

Comment: I only have one JAR, so there should be no order issue. Still, I'll try messing about with the filename, just to see...

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
 com.foo.bar.baz.theMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I
```

present in the new version of the jar?
If it is not is probable that mymacro.java was compiled againt a version of the jar which contained it

Comment: As mentioned in the question: same mymacro.java, same myjar.jar, same theMethod. I copied the exact same files over. I didn't make a "new version" or recompile.

Comment: ok but I guess you're executing class files and not java ones; are you sure mymacro.class has been compiled against the exactly same version of myjar.jar on both machines?

Comment: Technically, *I* am not executing class files, but the application is, presumably. I guess it compiles the java macro itself, using the supplied classpath. I don't think there was any ambiguity in my question and my previous comment: The JAR File "myjar.jar" Is Exactly The Same File On Both Machines.

Comment: if it is the same exact jar at compile time then your error is not due to what I thought; if it was the same at runtime it would not be relevant.
From what you wrote I can only desume for sure that it is the same at runtime